# ansible synchronize via ssh if inventory_hostname is different

Tags: ansible

I like to use the synchronize module in Ansible to synchronize files from one server to some other servers via SSH

```
    - name: Copy files to all servers
      synchronize:
        src: /source/path/
        dest: "rsync://{{ ansible_nodename }}:/destination/path/"
      delegate_to: src-host
```

So by default this module would use the inventory_name, but from the src-host the hostname is a different one. Only way I found so far was to use `rsync://{{ ansible_nodename }}`, but then it seems this is not happening via SSH anymore and I get a `No route to host (113)\nrsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [sender=3.1.0]`

I tried also to overwrite `inventory_hostname` just for this one task, with no luck so far.

So for example I imagine something like this

```
    - name: Copy custom config to all servers
      synchronize:
        src: /opt/app/dir/
        dest: /opt/app/dir/
      delegate_to: src-host
      vars:
        inventory_hostname: "{{ ansible_nodename }}"
```

But of course it fails when manipulating the inventory_hostname with following message

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: "hostvars['{{ ansible_nodename }}']" is undefined
fatal: [my-host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Comment: Would you mind to provide an example snippets?

Comment: @Halis what to you actually miss from aboves mentioned snippet? I add another example how I think it'll work with ssh, but actually it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy something

- *from* **serverA**
- *to* **serverB**
- *using* serverB's interface **eth4** address, it should be like this:

```yaml
 - name: Copy custom config from serverA serverB over
   synchronize:
     src: "/path/to/source/on/serverA/machine"
     dest: "rsync://{{ hostvars[serverB]['ansible_facts']['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }} }}/path/where/to/put/files/on/serverB/machines"
   delegate_to: serverA
```

Comment: Yes, but my problem starts, where the hostname/IP or actually `inventory_hostname` for the destination differs for what "serverA" should connect to internal IP.
So for example I connect with my ansible play to "host1-ext" and want to delegate to "serverA" so he synchronizes data to "host1-int"

Comment: @AndreasHubert I've edited my answer to take your comment into consideration.

Comment: the `rsync://` does it over the RSYNC protocol to a rsyncd, NOT via SSH ;(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to template target string based on some hostname, you can use:

- [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) `inventory_hostname`
- *(in case that your inventory hostname is not the real address)* [access other hosts variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) e.g.:
  `{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_facts']['ansible_fqdn']}}`

Comment: but for the synchronize module, when using `push` method, I would need to change inventory_hostname which leads to above error message